# изображение в виде кода

Tags: css

не могу понять, что это за код в css такой, и как его получают?

```
background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');
```

Comment: Читайте, что такое Base64

Answer (score 3):

В основном, чтобы хранить мелкие картинки строкой, а не файлом.

Кодируем изображение в base64 с помощью [онлайн сервисов](https://www.base64-image.de/).
Кладем получившуюся строку в CSS-файл, заменяя «ТИП» на MIME-тип (в зависимости от исходника вашего изображения) на jpeg/png/gif/svg+xml и «КОД» на нужную строку в base64, как в примере ниже:

```
.some_background {
    background-image: url("data:image/ТИП;base64,КОД");
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, то  есть была картинка в png? а тут её кодировали в base 64 ? И она в виде кода стала?

Comment: У вас картинка не PNG, а SVG.

Comment: Файл (и нет никакого значения, что за тип) является набором байтов. Берете ваш svg, кодируете его  помощью base64, а получившуюся строку - в CSS. При подгрузке происходит обратное декодирование.